# Remove degree two vertices from an undirected graph (Skiena TADM 5-22)

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-theory

From the Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd edition, question 5-22:

> Design a linear-time algorithm to eliminate each vertex v of degree 2 from a graph by replacing edges (u,v) and (v,w) by an edge (u,w). We also seek to eliminate multiple copies of edges by replacing them with a single edge. Note that removing multiple copies of an edge may create a new vertex of degree 2, which has to be removed, and that removing a vertex of degree 2 may create multiple edges, which also must be removed.

Because the question appears in the section on undirected graphs,
assume that our graph is undirected.

Here is an algorithm for removing vertices of degree two as desired, similar to the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125096/eliminating-vertices-from-a-graph).  The implementation relies on Skiena's graph, queue, and edgenode structs.  g->edges[v] is a pointer to the head of v's adjacency list.  g->M[u][v] returns the boolean value in row u and column v of g's adjacency matrix.

The problem:  according to my analysis, it does not work in linear time, no matter whether we use adjacency lists or adjacency matrices to represent our graph.

```
process_vertex(graph *g, int v, queue Q) {
    int u,w;
    if (degree[v] != 2) {return;}

    u = pop_first_edge(g,v); // O(n) for AL, O(n) for AM
    w = pop_first_edge(g,v); // O(n) for AL, O(n) for AM
    if (!edge_exists(g,u,w)) { // O(n) for AL, O(1) for AM
        insert_edge(g,u,w);
    }

    if (degree[u] == 2) {enqueue(Q,u);}
    if (degree[w] == 2) {enqueue(Q,w);}
}

remove_degree_twos(graph *g) {
    queue Q;
    for (int v = 1; v <= g->nvertices; ++v) {
        if (degree[v] == 2) {enqueue(Q,v);}
    }
    while (!Q.empty()) {
        process_vertex(g,dequeue(Q),Q);
    }
}
```

There are two required functions that have not yet been implemented:

```
// removes the first edge in v's adjacency list
// and updates degrees appropriately
// returns the vertex to which that edge points
int pop_first_edge(g,v);

// determines whether edge (u,v) already exists
// in graph g
bool edge_exists(g,u,v);
```

If g is represented with adjacency lists, then the required functions can be implemented as follows:

```
// O(n)
int pop_first_edge(g,v) {
    int u = -1; // the vertex to which the first outedge from v points
    edgenode *p = g->edges[v];

    if (p != NULL) {
        u = p->y;
        g->edges[v] = p->next;
        --(g->degree[v]);

        // delete v from u's adjacency list
        p1 = &g->edges[u];
        p2 = g->edges[u];
        while (p2 != NULL) {
            if (p2->y == v) {
                *p1 = p2->next;
                --(g->degree[u]);
                break;
            }
            p1 = p2;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
    }
}

// O(n)
edge_exists(g,u,w) {
    edgenode *p = g->edges[u];

    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->y == w) {
            return true;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If g is represented with adjacency matrices, then we have:

```
// O(n)
int pop_first_edge(v) {
    int u = -1;

    for (int j = 1; j <= g->nvertices; ++j) {
        if (M[v][j]) {
            u = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (u > 0) {
        M[v][u] = false;
        M[u][v] = false;
        --(g->degree[v]);
        --(g->degree[u]);
        return u;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

// O(1)
edge_exists(g,u,w) {
    return g->M[u][w];
}
```

No matter whether we use adjacency lists or adjacency matrices, the runtime of process_vertex is O(n), where n is the number of vertices in the graph.  Because O(n) vertices may be processed, the total runtime is O(n^2).

How can this be done in linear time?

Comment: From your comments, I am assuming this is a simple undirected graph - i.e. no multi-edges or looping edges - and if the reduction of the graph would create these edges then the existing edges are removed without replacement?

Comment: If the graph has a cycle: `{(1,2), (2,3), (3,2)}` what should the graph be reduced to?

Comment: Do you mean {(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)}?  Since the graph is undirected, (2,3) and (3,2) are the same edge -- or rather, according to skiena's implementation, one is present iff the other is also.

Comment: @MT0 Cycles are interesting.  There is more than one way to reduce them.  {(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)} can reduce to {(2,3)} or {(1,3)} or {(1,2)} depending on whether we delete vertex 1, 2, or 3 respectively.  I believe they are all valid outputs for the algorithm.  The presence of cycles makes the output non-unique, but after experimenting a little bit I conjecture that all outputs on the same input must be topologically equivalent, even if they may contain different sets of vertices.

Comment: @MT0 yes to your first comment on all counts.  Simple undirected graph, no multi-edges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have graph G=(V,E), where

```
V={1,...,n}
```

is set of vertices and E is set of edges, therefore subset of set

```
{(x,y) : x,y in V}
```

Usually the graph is given by the list of edges. Let's assume we receive it this way. Now:

1. make the set of edges distinct (O(m), m = |E|), consider the edges (x,y) and (y,x) equal
2. create an array representing the degree of each vertex in G (O(m) again)
3. for each vertex **v** of degree 2 make a list of those 2 edges (this is O(m), one iteration over the edges is sufficient)
4. at last iterate over the vertices of degree 2 and replace the related edges with one edge getting rid of vertex of degree 2 (this is O(n) operation)
5. repeat step 1. and return edges

Here's code written in python:

```
def remove_2_degree_vertices(n, edges):

    adj_matrix = [[0]*n for i in xrange(n)]

    #1 O(m)
    edges = get_distinct(adj_matrix, edges)

    #2 O(m)
    degrees = calculate_degrees(n, edges)

    #3 O(m)
    adj_lists = get_neighbours(degrees, edges)

    #4 O(n + m)
    to_remove, to_add_candidates = process(n, adj_lists)    
    edges.extend(to_add_candidates)
    result = [(e0,e1) for e0, e1 in edges if to_remove[e0][e1] == 0]

    #5 O(m)
    adj_matrix = [[0]*n for i in xrange(n)]
    result = get_distinct(adj_matrix, result)

    return result

def get_distinct(adj_matrix, edges):
    result = []
    for e0, e1 in edges:
        if adj_matrix[e0][e1] == 0:
            result.append((e0,e1))
            adj_matrix[e0][e1] = adj_matrix[e1][e0] = 1
    return result


def calculate_degrees(n, edges):
    result = [0]*n
    for e0, e1 in edges:
        result[e0] += 1
        result[e1] += 1
    return result


def get_neighbours(degrees, edges):
    result = {}
    for e0, e1 in edges:
        if degrees[e0] == 2:
            add_neighbour(result, e0, e1)
        if degrees[e1] == 2:
            add_neighbour(result, e1, e0)
    return result


def add_neighbour(neighbours, key, value):
    if not neighbours.has_key(key):
        neighbours[key] = set()
        neighbours[key].add(value)
    else:
        neighbours[key].add(value)


def process(n, adj_lists):
    to_remove = [[0 for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
    to_add_candidates = []

    if len(adj_lists) == 0:
        return to_remove, to_add_candidates

    for key in adj_lists:
        neighbours = list(adj_lists[key])
        if len(neighbours) == 1:
            to_remove[key][neighbours[0]] = to_remove[neighbours[0]][key] = 1
        else: # len(neighbours) == 2
            remove_edge(adj_lists, to_remove, key, neighbours[0], neighbours[1])
            remove_edge(adj_lists, to_remove, key, neighbours[1], neighbours[0])
            to_add_candidates.append((neighbours[0], neighbours[1]))

    return to_remove, to_add_candidates


def remove_edge(adj_lists, to_remove, key, n0, n1):
    to_remove[key][n0] = to_remove[n0][key] = 1
    if n0 in adj_lists:
        adj_lists[n0].remove(key)
        adj_lists[n0].add(n1)
```

Comment: Once step 4 is complete, we may have created new vertices of degree 2.  These vertices then need to be deleted, as indicated in the statement of the problem.  How do we address that issue?  If we repeat steps 3 and 4 until no degree-2 vertices remain, we end up with quadratic runtime.

Comment: Actually we couldn't. Assume we have vertices **x**,**y**,**z** and edges (**x**,**y**) and (**y**,**z**). Therefore **x**,**z** are of degree 1 and **z** is of degree 2. Removing **y** we have vertices **x**,**z** and edge (**x**,**z**) and both vertices are still degree 1. In general you do not change the degree of vertex, the edge is simply exchanged by another one. Only when step 1 is complete we might have created vertices of degree 2 and that's fine since we are just starting.

Comment: And in step 5 we are repeating step 1 but there are no more vertices of degree 2. So if there is duplicated of edge, it is odd duplicate and we are still fine.

Comment: I think you mean "y is of degree 2", not "z is of degree 2", right?

Comment: x and z may be connected to other vertices and their degrees need not be one prior to deletion of vertex y.  The problem arises not when degree[x] == 1 but rather when degree[x] == 3 and the edge (x,z) **already exists** prior to deletion of vertex y.  In this case, degree[x] does decrease by 1 when edge (x,y) is deleted, leaving degree[x] = 2 and requiring that x be deleted, even though its degree was 3 during the initial pass.  As far as I can see, your algorithm doesn't account for this possibility.

Comment: Also, I don't know much Python, but it looks like you are initializing an n x n adjacency matrix to be all zeros.  It takes quadratic time just to perform such an initialization - that is, to write n^2 zeroes into memory.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, obviously I meant **y**.

Comment: And I must say you are right with both next comments. The adjecancy matrix initialization can be ignored if we assume that it is provided as input together with edges (Skiena is not specifiing input at all) and small adjustment in #5. But what about the first problem? Unfortunately I can't debug right now, let's think about it and get back to it later.